# Maven Local file installation

Tags: maven

I am trying to install a local jar file to be used as a dependency using the following command

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>
```

Getting the following result

The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory

Comment: Why do you try to install a file via install-file? Why not defining it as a dependency? Where is that file coming from?

Answer (score 0):

To install the file in the local maven repository, you have to provide also the group ID, artifact ID, and the version for that file. Without them, Maven does not know in what directory to store the file.

See also: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html.

Answer (score 0):

Maven need the so called GAV coordinates: `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version` and `packaging` to store the artefact.

You can name them wiht the install command

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file 
   -Dfile=<path-to-file> 
   -Dpackaging=jar
   -DgeneratePom=true
   -DgroupId=<groupId> -DartifactId=<artifactId> -Dversion=<version>
```